# How do I use compose outputs for a Create Event flow?

Tags: power-automate

Beginner Level User

I am trying to create a flow that triggers when an item is created in a SharePoint list. When the conditions in my flow are met I want to look for available meeting times for the group and then book the first available with 100% confidence of all attending. I figured out how to find the times and use the compose action. The issue is that I have set the "max candidate" to 1 thinking that would only return one option for the output. When I add the "output" to the create event action I get an error. I am so new to this I don't really know what is wrong. Below is a screenshot of the flow and the error. I would appreciate any tips or advice that can help me figure out where I am going wrong.

[image]